# Change object property in nested array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, recursion, nested

I have an array:

```
   const array = [
      { id: 1, parent_id: 0, visible: true },
      { id: 2, parent_id: 0, visible: true },
      { id: 3, parent_id: 1, visible: true },
      { id: 4, parent_id: 3, visible: true },
      { id: 5, parent_id: 4, visible: true },
      { id: 6, parent_id: 4, visible: true },
      { id: 7, parent_id: 3, visible: true },
      { id: 8, parent_id: 2, visible: true }
    ]
```

I want to create a function with arguments ID and ARRAY, that return new array with VISIBLE = FALSE for this ID and every nested child by PARENT_ID.

My effort is like this

```
const result = []

const findFitstHandler = (id, arr) => {
  let j
  for (let i in arr) {
    if (arr[i].id === id) {
      result.push(arr[i].id)
      j = arr[i].id
    }
  }
  findNested(j, arr)

  return array.map(item => {
    if (result.includes(item.id)) {
      return {
        ...item,
        visible: false
      }
    } else {
      return item
    }
  })
}

const findNested = (id, arr) => {
  for (let i in arr) {
    if (arr[i].parent_id === id) {
      result.push(arr[i].id)
      findNested(arr[i].id, arr)
    }
  }
}
```

I'm sure there is a more elegant solution. Please, help me

Answer (score 0):

Try with array map method:

```js
const array = [
      { id: 1, parent_id: 0, visible: true },
      { id: 2, parent_id: 0, visible: true },
      { id: 3, parent_id: 1, visible: true },
      { id: 4, parent_id: 3, visible: true },
      { id: 5, parent_id: 4, visible: true },
      { id: 6, parent_id: 4, visible: true },
      { id: 7, parent_id: 3, visible: true },
      { id: 8, parent_id: 2, visible: true }
    ];
    
const getNewArray = (id, items) => items.map(item => {
   if ([item.id, item.parent_id].includes(id)) {
      item.visible = false;
   }
   
   return item;
});    

console.log(getNewArray(4, array));
```

Answer (score 0):

I would break apart the recursive code that finds the list of descendants from the code that does the data manipulation.  Here's one possibility:

```js
const descendants = (array, root) => 
  [
    root, 
    ...array .filter (({parent_id}) => parent_id == root) 
             .flatMap (({id}) => descendants (array, id))
  ]

const changeBranch = (fn) => (array, root, keys = descendants (array, root)) =>
  array .map (element => keys .includes (element .id) ? fn (element) : element)

const makeInvisible = changeBranch (
  ({visible, ...rest}) => ({...rest, visible: false})
)

const array = [{ id: 1, parent_id: 0, visible: true }, { id: 2, parent_id: 0, visible: true }, { id: 3, parent_id: 1, visible: true }, { id: 4, parent_id: 3, visible: true }, { id: 5, parent_id: 4, visible: true }, { id: 6, parent_id: 4, visible: true }, { id: 7, parent_id: 3, visible: true }, { id: 8, parent_id: 2, visible: true }];
    
console .log (makeInvisible (array, 4))

console .log (makeInvisible (array, 2))
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper {min-height: 100% !important; top: 0}
```

**`descendants`** finds the ids of the root id supplied and all the nodes descendant from it inside your array.

**`changeBranch`** takes a function to transform a node and returns a function that takes an array and the root id and returns a new array containing either the result of applying that function (when the node is descendant from the root) or the original value (when it isn't.)

**`makeInvisible`** is the result of applying to `changeBranch` a function which sets `visible` to `false`.  This is the final function you're looking for.

Note that if your list is cyclic and not hierarchical, this will not work.  Your stack would likely overflow.